# Handling POST ARRAY in PHP and array_filter

Tags: php, html, arrays, post, multidimensional-array

Here is my POST Array PHP

```
    Array
    (

    [book_count] => 2

    [book_code_1] => 230
    [book_name_1] => 20

    [book_code_2] => 210
    [book_name_2] => 40

    [book_code_3] => 
    [book_name_3] => 60

    [book_code_4] => 
    [book_name_4] => 80

    [book_code_5] => 
    [book_name_5] => 90

    )
```

In the above array, I get the book_count. i.e 2
What I want to do is.
There will be five array and i need to get the values of array with respect to that of book_count.

In other words - in the above case, the book count is 2, and I need to get

```
    [book_code_1] => 230
    [book_name_1] => 20

    [book_code_2] => 210
    [book_name_2] => 40
```

I need to eliminate the other array(in this case 3 to 5) values irrespective of the values. How can I achieve that?

I have tried

```
<?php $new_array = array_filter($_POST) ?>
```

but this is eliminating only the null values.

Comment: loop through your array var

Comment: You can do that simple iteration. See my answer and demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155952/handling-post-array-in-php-and-array-filter/24156161#24156161)

Comment: huseyin - yup, marked and up-voted your answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/z66pEkY3)**

You can do that with simple iteration like below;

```
$arr = array(

    "book_count" => 2,

    "book_code_1" => 230,
    "book_name_1" => 20,

    "book_code_2" => 210,
    "book_name_2" => 40,

    "book_code_3" => "",
    "book_name_3" => 60,

    "book_code_4" => "",
    "book_name_4" => 80,

    "book_code_5" => "",
    "book_name_5" => 90

    );

$result = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $arr["book_count"]; $i++) {
    $result["book_code_" . $i] = $arr["book_code_" . $i];
    $result["book_name_" . $i] = $arr["book_name_" . $i];
}

var_dump($result);
```